# Workaround for latexindent bug

Tags: latexindent

Running `latexindent` I get the following error message:

```
YAML::Tiny found a duplicate key 'pmatrix' in line '1' at    /usr/local/texlive/2014/bin/x86_64-linux/latexindent line 171.
```

The bug resists:

- Reinstallation (working on Ubuntu 14.10)
- Removal of all configuration files
- Logging in from another user account.

Any ideas for a workaround?

---

**Edit:** the problem persists even after upgrade to `latexindent` version 2.0R, with the date of the `latexindent.pl` being Dec 7th, 2014:

[image]

Comment: Which version do you have (you should see details in indent.log)? Have you updated your distribution? I fixed this issue in v2.0r which was released in December 2014

Comment: It `latexindent.pl version 1.11R`; strangely enough, I never had this problem before.

Comment: Try updating your distribution, and then running it again. The problem was that `defaultSettings.yaml` did indeed contain a duplicated entry, `pmatrix`. In older versions of `YAML::Tiny` this wasn't an issue, but presumably you have a newer version. Let me know if this fixes the issue or not once you see `version 2.0R` in `indent.log`

Comment: Did you update defaultSettings.yaml as well?

Comment: Yes, I did. But my `~/.latexinde.yaml` had a copy of the old `defaultSettings.yaml`. Fixing this solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has been solved by updating the software.

Comment: Not so fast. The problem was with the update process, in which some of the old config files intervene with the new update. It may occur again in any system in which you update an existing version of TeXLive, or keeping up two, as may be common in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

This can be fixed by updating your version of `latexindent.pl` to `V2.0R` by updating your distribution, as detailed in [How do I update my TeX distribution?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55437/how-do-i-update-my-tex-distribution). If you download `latexindent.pl` manually, be sure to get `defaultSettings.yaml` at the same time.

---

This issue was actually fixed in a [previous commit](https://github.com/cmhughes/latexindent.pl/commit/dba4ba6e48a53c8ae13c0a5ffdf222d99cfe40fd) in June 2014. The issue was that `defaultSettings.yaml` contained the following:

```
# environments that have tab delimiters, add more 
# as needed
lookForAlignDelims:
   ...
   pmatrix: 1
   ...
   pmatrix: 1
   ...
```

This didn't cause problems in older versions of the `YAML::Tiny` Perl Module, but does give the warning you report in newer versions.